# Accessing dynamically created inputs

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have the following code

```
createPhone(): void {
    const widgetFactory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory( PhoneComponent );
    this.componentRef =
        this.container.createComponent( widgetFactory );
    this.componentRef.instance.containerRef = this.container;
  }
```

In the PoneComponent where the dynamic input is created/attached, in which lifecycle method of PhoneComponent can I access this.componentRef.instance.containerRef?

I am getting an undefined for each lifecyle method used.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it in any lifecycle method except `ngOnChanges` because with your above code the value is assigned before any lifecycle method was called. 
`ngOnChanges` is not called because there can't be any bindings for dynamically added components.

Also the constructor can not be used, because the assignment is done after the construction of the component.

Ensure that `this.container` is defined.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/OvQkbOv1WtC5HpZg8Lj1?p=preview)